# Best way to create expandable menu?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What's the best way to create menu like in attached photos ?

I tried to make it with:

```
const [firstParentActive, setFirstParentActive] = useState(false) // idea is to make useStates for all category parents and category children  
 
const activeHandler = () => {...} // all handlers for setting 'true' in such category parents
 <div
   className={classes[`FullServices__parent-${active}`]}
   onClick={() => activeHandler()}
>
     Кузов
</div>
```

This way seemed to me very uncomfy and not universal. Furthermore I will refactor it all using redux-toolkit

[initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lbVo.png)

[expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtZqg.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to use accordion menus
Add following code in src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const accordionData = {
    title: 'Section 1',
    content: `Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sapiente
      laborum cupiditate possimus labore, hic temporibus velit dicta earum
      suscipit commodi eum enim atque at? Et perspiciatis dolore iure
      voluptatem.`
  };

  const { title, content } = accordionData;

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h1>React Accordion Demo</h1>
          <div className="accordion">
            <div className="accordion-item">
              <div className="accordion-title">
                <div>{title}</div>
                <div>+</div>
              </div>
              <div className="accordion-content">{content}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```